# Impossible to calculate a difference of time in Android using System.currentTimeMillis()

Tags: java, android, time

I'm developing a little Android app to calculate the time it takes to hit a square with another square using the accelerometer of the phone.

I have a custom View defined as follows : (I removed several declarations for readability purpose)

```
public class BallView extends View implements SensorEventListener {

    private long startTime = 0;
    private long endTime = 0;
    private long time = 0;

    public BallView( Context context) {
        super( context);
        init( context );
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        size = 200;
        orignSize = size;
        rectBall.set(currentX,currentY,currentX+size,currentY+size);
        rectviseur.set(getWidth()/2-10,getHeight()/2-10,getWidth()/2-5,getHeight()/2-5);
        vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        startT();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        currentX = 0;
        currentY = 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        rectviseur.set(getWidth()/2-4,getHeight()/2-4,getWidth()/2+4,getHeight()/2+4);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        paintViseur.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        rectBall.set(currentX,currentY,currentX+size,currentY+size);
        canvas.drawRect(rectBall,paint);
        canvas.drawRect(rectviseur,paintViseur);
        paint.setTextSize(20);

        canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(time),300,300,paint);
    }

    private void moveImage( float x, float y ) {
        currentX += (int) x;
        currentY += (int) y;

        if ( currentX < 0 ) {
            currentX = 0;
        } else if ( currentX + size > getWidth() ){
            this.currentX = getWidth() - size;
        }

        if ( currentY < 0 ) {
            currentY = 0;
        } else if ( currentY + size > getHeight() ){
            currentY = getHeight() - size;
        }

        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {}

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER ) {
            x = event.values[0];
            y = event.values[1];
            z = event.values[2];
        }
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE ) {
            xg = event.values[0];
            yg = event.values[1];
            zg = event.values[2];
        }

        this.moveImage( -x*5, -(z-(float)5.5)*5 );
        hit();
    }

    public void hit(){
        if (rectBall.contains(rectviseur)) {
            //vibrate
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
                vibrator.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(200, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
            } else {
                vibrator.vibrate(200);
            }


            //replace the rectangle
            size = size-20;
            currentX = random.nextInt(getWidth()-size);
            currentY = random.nextInt(getHeight()-size);
            if (size < 8) {
                size= orignSize;
            }

            stopT();
            time = time(startTime, endTime);

            startT();
        }
    }

    private void startT() {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    private void stopT() {
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    private long time(long start, long end) {
       return (end - start);
    }
}
```

I have 3 variables `startTime` to store the current time when the game is launched (or restarted), `endTime` to store the current time when the square was hit, and `time` to calculate the time it took.

I affect `startTime` and `endTime` by calling respectively `startT()` and `stopT()`. The first affectation of `startTime` is in the `init` method. And I display the result with `canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(time),300,300,paint);`

As you can see when the the square hit the other square the method `hit()` is called. At the end of this method, I call `stopT()` to store the time when the square was hit and I call the `time` method to calculate the time it took. Then I recall `startT()` because the game restart.

So technically the `startTime` is supposed to contains something like "1607303475300" and `endTime` something like "1607303477350". But I get completely incoherent result in `time` everytime. Like 5, 7 or 8 while the time is in millisecond which is impossible. I really can't understand why. I tried several solution, none of them worked so I'm seeking for your help.

**Edit :**
Also here's my MainActivity class that uses my BallView:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private BallView ballView;
    private SensorManager sensorManager = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ballView = new BallView(this);
        ballView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        setContentView(ballView);

        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        sensorManager.registerListener(
                ballView,
                sensorManager.getDefaultSensor( Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER ),
                sensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME );
        sensorManager.registerListener(
                ballView,
                sensorManager.getDefaultSensor( Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE ),
                sensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        sensorManager.unregisterListener( ballView );
    }
}
```

Comment: *Like 5, 7 or 8 while the time is in millisecond which is impossible* Why do you think it is impossible? Computers perform BILLIONS of operations per second.

Comment: Yeah but it is supposed to be a human time (like 2 or 3 seconds) because it is a human who moves the square.

Comment: You should check if the successful hit detection part of your code is called multiple times in a row as it seems to be happening here. How do you register with the `SensorManager`? Do you use a separate thread to receive the events?

Comment: @GergelyKőrössy I edited my question to add my class ```MainActivity``` where the ```SensorManager``` is registered. I don't use a separate thread. But you're right, what happens is that my method ```hit()``` get called several time in a row. I don't know how I can limit it to be called only once but still be able to use it when the square position is completely reset.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I understood from your question, if you are looking to convert the milliseconds into seconds, you can do this operation.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long inSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(currentTime);
        System.out.println(inSeconds +" Seconds = "+currentTime +" Milliseconds");
    }
```

Output:

```
1607305686 Seconds = 1607305686504 Milliseconds
```

Answer (score 1):

I see no restriction that OnSensorChanged gets called exactly once.  Suppose there's an accelerometer event shortly followed by a gyroscope event.  Since you only retain 'the last time', you end up with the interval between the two events.

---

An alternative is to consider that calls that are 'close together' are part of the same interval being timed. Let me try and sketch this approach. I favour one timing method rather than three.

```
    // This is an estimate of how much time needs to
    // elapse before we consider an 'event' to be the
    // first in a new timing interval.  3 seconds is
    // just my guess; it depends on what you want.
    final static long shortInterval = 3_000;

    // Clock time at start of new interval
    long intervalStart = 0; 

    // Elapsed time in interval since last call
    long elapsed = 0;

     // The timer.  Call on every sensor event.
    void intervalTimer() {
        long now = System.currentTimeMilliseconds();
        if (now - intervalStart > shortInterval)
             intervalStart = now;
        elapsed = now - intervalStart;
    }
```

And there you are.  Call `intervalTimer` from your init method and from the end of OnSensorChanged.  The measurement will automatically reset whenever the time between calls exceeds the `shortInterval` value. The value of `elapsed` is available whenever you need to use it.

Comment: I think that's exactly what happens, my function hit() does get call several time in a row when a square hit the other square (maybe during the time it takes to reset the position of the square). Thank you. But I don't know how I can limit it to be called only once but still be able to use it when the square position is completely reset.

Comment: You can consider calls to OnSensorChanged that occur 'sufficiently close together' to be part of the same interval, so you want to calculate the elapsed time from the first to the last such calls, not from the 'time before last' to the last.  See my updated answer for an approach.